# Environment variables in gatsby-browser.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to make a Keycloak integration with Gatsby.

I'd love to use environment variables for the Keycloak configuration so that I can properly containerize the application. I'm facing an issue about gatsby-browser.js that doesn't get environment variables.

Here's my gatsby-browser.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { node } from 'prop-types'
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'
import { KeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'
import { Spinner } from 'design-react-kit'

require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.development`
})

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  realm: process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
  url: process.env.KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URL,
  clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_AUTH_CLIENT_ID
})

const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Spinner
        active
        double
        small={false}
        tag="span"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <KeycloakProvider
      keycloak={keycloak}
      initConfig={{
        promiseType: 'native',
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.xhtml'
      }}
      LoadingComponent={<Loading />}
    >
      {element}
    </KeycloakProvider>
  )
}

wrapRootElement.propTypes = {
  element: node
}

const _wrapRootElement = wrapRootElement
export { _wrapRootElement as wrapRootElement }
```

When I launch `gatsby develop` I get:

```
Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/gbiagini/Documents/work/appaltinnovativi/swg-service/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'fs' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.

File: node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js

failed Building development bundle - 13.100s
```

I don't get why the `fs` package should be an issue considering that I do the exact same process on gatsby-config.js and works flawlessly.

Comment: At this stage, you are on "client side", so env variables dont exist any more! You must use Gatsby SSR api to pass them

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Gatsby's documentation about Environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/#client-side-javascript) your client-side variables must be prefixed with `GATSBY_` to make them available to the client.

> **Client-side JavaScript**
>
> For Project Env Vars that you want to access in
> client-side browser JavaScript, you can define an environment config
> file, `.env.development` and/or `.env.production`, in your root folder.
> Depending on your active environment, the correct one will be found
> and its values embedded as environment variables in the browser
> JavaScript.
>
> In addition to these Project Environment Variables defined in `.env.*`
> files, you could also define OS Env Vars. OS Env Vars which are
> prefixed with `GATSBY_` will become available in browser JavaScript.

So, you will need to prefix your `.env` variables and update your code:

```
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  realm: process.env.GATSBY_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
  url: process.env.GATSBY_KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URL,
  clientId: process.env.GATSBY_KEYCLOAK_AUTH_CLIENT_ID
})
```

Comment: Or use this... https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-env-variables/